# In CQ5, why does the 'checkbox' xtype not work? But a 'selection' xtype and a 'checkbox' type is needed to create a working checkbox in a dialog?

Tags: jsp, checkbox, aem

So there is an xtype called 'checkbox'. When I apply this to a cq:widget, the check box shows up in the dialog but the information doesn't get passed into the JSP. I was trying to make a checkbox that controls the input type of a `<input>` html tag.

After looking around, I found that the proper way to create a checkbox is with a xtype set as 'selection' and type set as 'checkbox' and it works.The only thing I changed is the type and the xtype.

Here's how I'm using it in the JSP

```
    <%final boolean checked= properties.get("checkbox", false);
    request.setAttribute("checked", checked);%>

    <input type = <c:out value="${checked?'text':'password'}"/>
```

I was wondering what's the difference between the two approaches, why doesn't the first approach work?

EDIT: Or rather, how is the xtype 'checkbox' suppose to be used? What is it actually for?

Comment: I can't answer why there is an xtype="checkbox" which doesn't work. But I just live with the xtype="selection" and type="checkbox" and never used anything else in years.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `properties.get("checked", false)` for xtype=checkbox? There is no property called "checkbox".

Comment: @EminCanSümer you can define the name of the widgets property, so if it is called "checkbox" in the dialog it should work with either xtype. The problem with xtype="checkbox" is in my experience, once checked, you can't uncheck it and the property stays on "true" or "checked".

Comment: @Thomas actually xtype=checkbox needs a hidden field with "fieldname@Delete" value for uncheck state to be saved. xtype=selection adds that hidden field automatically.

Comment: @EminCanSümer after many years working with CQ, I still learn stuff, thanks!

Comment: @EminCanSümer So what are the differences between using a hidden field vs the xtype selection? Are there situations where using the xtype="checkbox" is more suitable than xtype="selection" with type="checkbox"?

Comment: @Synia no difference except the thing I mentioned afaik. So I'd always prefer the simpler and more flexible which is selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the 'checkbox' xtype doesn't work because it is designed in a way that doesn't preserve the state on its own, as @Emin commented.

When a user loads a component that uses a 'checkbox' xtype in the dialog, the first load of that page the underlying JCR node does not have any dialog properties stored for that checkbox because it hasn't been author-configured yet.  Then, if the author checks the box to configure it and saves the dialog, the form submission in the dialog will include the selection and the property will be saved the the repository as having been checked.

But then if the author later changes things and *unchecks* the box, the dialog form submission won't include anything about this checkbox, so the underlying property in the JCR repository isn't touched--it remains as-is, which indicates the box as having been checked. So when the author re-loads the page, the box is still checked (not what the author wanted).

The xtype of 'selection' saves you from having to deal with this.

Comment: Hmmm... so why is there a 'checkbox' xtype in the first place? Are there circumstances where the 'checkbox' xtype is prefered over the 'selection' xtype?